# save XML list with c#

Tags: c#, xml, c#-4.0, c#-3.0, c#-2.0

```
 var xusabugun = root.Elements().Where(s => s.Element("geoId").Value == "US"
                  && DateTime.Parse(s.Element("dateRep").Value).Date == DateTime.Now.Date);
```

I want to save this code as an xml file. I would appreciate if those who can help. Thank you from now!

Comment: you want to save the result in xml file?have you used ``XDocument``?

Comment: @sajid Yes, I want to save the result in xml file. I received the data from the internet.

Comment: Your results from the query is an array.  So you can create a new document with a root.   Then add the array to the root.  Finally save the new document.

Comment: @jdweng Yes, this is a list and therefore I cannot register. Can you write the code that will allow me to register?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try following :

```
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load("filename");
            XElement root = doc.Root;
            List<XElement> xusabugun = root.Elements()
                .Where(s => s.Element("geoId").Value == "US" && DateTime.Parse(s.Element("dateRep").Value).Date == DateTime.Now.Date)
                .ToList();

            XDocument newDoc = XDocument.Parse("<root></root>");
            XElement newRoot = newDoc.Root;
            newRoot.Add(xusabugun);
            newDoc.Save("new filename");
```